# when I execute isql connect statement nothing happens

Tags: unix, odbc, isql

When i Am running the command:
`isql -v [dsn] [uname] [pwd]` nothing happens and the command line is just plain silent...

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... my dumb ass just put down the wrong hostname, and the timeout was set to 60min by the default installation... *ghee* fixed now :)